# Dropbox pod install Error - Higher Minimum Deployment Required?

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, dropbox

Getting this message when attempting to install Dropbox- higher minimum deployment target required. I am on iOS 9.3. Any ideas?

$ pod install
Analyzing dependencies
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Ensembles/Dropbox":
In Podfile:
Ensembles/Dropbox (~> 2.0)

Specs satisfying the Ensembles/Dropbox (~> 2.0) dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the highest version of the Ensembles Pod available publicly is 1.8 and the Podfile is requesting 2.0 - https://cocoapods.org/pods/Ensembles.

If you have additional questions, please share the Podfile.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  The developer has conflicting versions listed in his doc and then the files were too large.  Pods are a waste of time much easier to just copy in the files and libraries.